# Setting up Amazon Linux instance for CodeDeploy with IAM user credentials

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, aws-cli, aws-code-deploy

I have created all that are needed for a successful deployment.
I tried to make the deployment without configuring the CodeDeploy agent in the Amazon instance and the deployment [obviously] failed.
After setting it up though, succeeded. 
So, my question is, should I configure every instance that I use manually?
What if I have 100 instances in the deployment group?
Should I create an AMI with the CodeDeploy agent tool already configured?

EDIT

I have watched this: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qZa5JXmsWZs

with this:
https://github.com/andrewpuch/code_deploy_example

and read this: 
http://blogs.aws.amazon.com/application-management/post/Tx33XKAKURCCW83/Automatically-Deploy-from-GitHub-Using-AWS-CodeDeploy

I just cannot understand why I must configure with the IAM creds the instance. Isn't it supposed to take the creds from the role I launched it with?
I am not an expert in aws roles and policies, but from the CD documentation this is what I understood.
Is there a way to give the IAM user access to the instance so I wont have to setup the CD agent?

EDIT 2

I think that this post kind of answers:  http://adndevblog.typepad.com/cloud_and_mobile/2015/04/practice-of-devops-with-aws-codedeploy-part-1.html

`But as you can see, I launched multiple instances but I only installed CodeDeploy agent on one instance, what about others? Do I have to repeat myself and login to them and install them separately? It is OK since I just have 2 or 3. But what if I have handers or even thousand of instances? Actually there are different solutions for this. One of them is, I setup all environment on one instances and create an AMI from it. When I launch my working instance, I will create instance from the one I’ve already configured instead of the AWS default ones. Some other solutions are available`

Comment: Are you saying that assigning an IAM role to the EC2 instance didn't work for some reason?

Comment: @Rodrigo M : I think I have mistaken the aws-cli with the CD agent. Really sorry for the confusion. I will edit my question.

Comment: @Mark B : If assigning the IAM role to the EC2 instance meant that I would not have to configure the CodeDeploy agent, then yes. As I understand, I have created 2 roles but I am confused as for their usage and necessity.

Answer (score 1):

Each instance only requires the CodeDeploy agent installed on it. It does not require the AWS CLI to be installed. See [AWS CodeDeploy Agent Operations](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/how-to-run-agent.html) for installation and operation details.

You should create an instance profile/role in IAM that will grant any instance the correct permissions to accept a code deployment through CodeDeploy service.

Create a role called ApplicationServer. To this role, add the following policy. This assumes you are using S3 for your revisions:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:Get*",
                "s3:List*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::codedeploy-example-com/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1414002531000",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "cloudwatch:PutMetricData"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1414002720000",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "logs:CreateLogGroup",
                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "logs:DescribeLogGroups",
                "logs:DescribeLogStreams",
                "logs:PutLogEvents"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

To your specific questions:

> So, my question is, should I configure every instance that I use
>   manually?
>
> What if I have 100 instances in the deployment group? Should I create
>   an AMI with the aws-cli tool already configured?

Configure AMI with your base tools, or use CloudFormation or puppet to manage software installation on a given instance as needed. Again the AWS CLI is not required for CodeDeploy. Only the most current version of the CodeDeploy agent is required.